# Linq to sql truncating string returned by Stored Procedure

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have asked this question before. but i was not able to get any answer. may be i wasnt very clear. let me give some more details.

I have a SP which returns a long string. here is dbml file code

```
[Function(Name="dbo.spX")]
public ISingleResult<spXResult> spX([Parameter(DbType="VarChar(8000)")] string str)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), str);
    return ((ISingleResult<spXResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

and here is spXResult class

```
public partial class spXResult
{
    private string _XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B;

    public spXResult()
    {  }

    [Column(Name="[XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B]", 
     Storage="_XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B", 
     DbType="NText", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B
    {
        get
        {
            return this._XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B != value))
            {
                this._XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B = value;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

and here is my code

```
ISingleResult<spXResult> result = ctx.spX("1234");

string returnStr = result.First().XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B;
```

everything is fine, when the result is not a long string, but as soon as the sp returns a very long string, it truncates the result. i have no clue why.. can someone please help.

thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the length of a "very long string" please? Also, which database server are you using and have you verified that the string is not getting truncated in the db?

Comment: im using SQL server 2005, and no its not getting truncated at the database server. well.. i dont know the exact length, but may be after 8000 character. do you think i should try IMultipleResults?

Comment: If your column definition is varchar(8000) and the data is 8001 characters or more, it is getting truncated at the database. The code you have here also appears to be dealing with XML data. Sql Server 2005 has an XML datatype for this which may better suit your purpose.

Comment: Seeing code like that, I would just shut off PC and go home.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing fishy I can spot is this - here in the declaration, you hvae:

```
public ISingleResult<spXResult> spX([Parameter(DbType="VarChar(8000)")] string str)
```

(DbType=VARCHAR(8000)) - which is ANSI (non-Unicode), but then in the column declaration you use NTEXT - first of all, that's UNICODE (2-byte per character), and why NTEXT?? Above you have VARCHAR?

```
[Column(Name="[XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B]", 
     Storage="_XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B", 
     DbType="NText", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
```

That seems a bit odd.......

Can you try to make it the same in both places? E.g. VARCHAR(8000) in both cases??

Marc

Comment: I tried that too .actually i modified the method to return IMULtipleResults and look thru to get the rest of the string.. the behavior is weird. may be somehthing is limitng the return string length

Comment: Can you check in the DB how long those strings are?? SELECT (string), DATALENGTH(string) FROM (table) - and see if any are indeed more than 8000 characters??

Answer (score 1):

LinqToSql splits the XML result set into chunks, so you need to run a loop like this:

```
ISingleResult<spXResult> result = ctx.spX("1234");
string xml = "";
foreach (var x in result)
    xml += x.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B;
```

Or using LINQ:

```
string xml = result.Aggregate("", (current, x) => current + x.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sp from

```
SELECT ...
  FROM MyTable
  FOR XML AUTO
```

to

```
DECLARE @ResultXML xml

SET @ResultXML = 
 (SELECT ...
  FROM MyTable
  FOR XML AUTO)

SELECT @ResultXML as [MyXML]
```

and recreate linq method