# Increase dbx_query row length

Tags: php, sql-server, xml

I'm fetching an int and a xml-string from a Microsoft Sqlserver 2012 (on windows) with PHP Version 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 on debian.

The XML comes from

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[XMLproduct]
(@id integer)
RETURNS xml
...
```

The query is `SELECT id,dbo.XMLproduct(id) FROM ...`

I'm using `dbx_query($_db_handle, $query, DBX_RESULT_INDEX)`.

But when the xml is long, it gets truncated.

In php, when the xml is truncated, the row size is 5 (int)+ 32257 (xml) = 32262.

Is there a way to increase row length?

There is a number of rather large nodes called `<audit>` in the XML, I don't really need, can i remove it in the query before it gets sent to php?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044432/linq-to-sql-truncating-string-returned-by-stored-procedure

Comment: Not really. But if I could make this work:
https://www.example-code.com/sql/xml_remove_child.asp to remove the unneded nodes...

Comment: I worked around the problem by modifying the function to not return the large <audit> (Basically a row for each transaction on the product)